# Accessing Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT setting.py values from ReactJS frontend

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, reactjs

I have a Django web application and am using ReactJS for my frontend. My application wants to retrieve local music files when I'm developing locally (folder containing my music files) and also on production (file system on server). Both have different paths so I have a different settings for dev and prod.

I set

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'music')    # on dev env
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

where "music" is my folder containing the files.

I added

`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

to my urls.py but when ReactJs is rendering the component it's treating that variable as just a string and not getting the value that I set

`<audio src={"{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}" + props.audio}></audio>`

where props.audio is the path to the file.

I also added

```
django.core.context_processors.media
```

to the TEMPLATES in my settings.py but it still doesn't work

However, when I type in the url 'localhost:8000/media/path/to/music.wav', I can see the file.

Any ideas on how to get the value of MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT from my javascript? or do I have to make a get call to my Django backend to retrieve those values everytime I render the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/) property of file field.
If for example you have FileField 'audio' in your model you can try this to get file's url:

```
{{ props.audio.url }}
```

But if you dont have model and in your view there is some variable contains file's url 'props.audio' you can pass it from view to template:

```
def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'props_url': props.audio})
```

Now in template to get url simple do following:

```
{{ props_url }}
```

Comment: i'm not using any models though, would that be the best way to approach it? create a model for the files?

Comment: @user3226932 can you show what is props.audio and How do you pass it to template? I suppose the problem is that Django cannto parse this `{"{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}" + props.audio}` as url. Can you do string concatenation in view and pass result to the template?

Comment: I guess that's the problem. I'm not passing it to Django template, I'm using ReactJS to render the view, not Django, either way I think I'll have to make a call to django backend to get those values?

Comment: props.audio is just the path to the file, and isn't the "url" thing for django and can't be used with reactjs?

Comment: @user3226932 sorry I did not work with ReactJS, so only one way I can help you is to tell how Django usually works with file. See my updated answer.